# iOS App does not like self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: ios, openssl, self-signed-certificate

We developed an iOS app, which works fine with our API on the production server, but not plays well with other servers with self-signed SSL certificate, I searched a lot for solutions, some of which say adding exception to APP config, some says generating a self-signed certificate, none of gives clear step-by-step answer. After a lot of research/experiments, I finally get this DONE, I post the question and answer here in case it can help others too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate the self-signed certificate with V3 support
   copy the code here and modify according to your env
   https://gist.github.com/rdj/921a55bb56d4bc62bb52
2. Install certificate onto your device and install/trust certificates on your device by following the instructions here:https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/self-signed-certificates-in-ios-apps-ff489bf8b96e

I have done these stuff on MAC, you should be able to make it work on any other OS.

More info, iOS 13 has more strict requirements on SSL certificate
 https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176